# Import backbone template text in ES2015

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, ecmascript-6

Anyone know how to import backbone template in **ES2015**.

I saw an example [from this site](http://benmccormick.org/2015/07/06/backbone-and-es6-classes-revisited/)

```
import * as todosTemplate from 'text!templates/todos.html';
```

The main problem is 'text!', how can I setup this one **without Require.js**?

P.S. have no luck with [handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/installation.html) and require-text in ES2015, only found solutions using require.js.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't require text as modules without a module loader that supports it explicitly, such as requirejs. And what's wrong with that? Just transpile your ES6 modules to AMD.

Comment: It already work for me with requirejs, I was wondering aproach for achieve same result via naitive ES2015 modules.

Comment: "Native ES2015" does not include a module loader, it's up to the loader how it resolves paths (or handles prefix commands like `text!`) and what kind of module records it lets you import.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the * and just state the variable name of your choice. Like the code below:

```
import rootTemplate from './templates/rootTemplate.hbs';
```